# Push notifications don't work in iOS7 but they work in iOS6

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, apple-push-notifications

I'm having problems with push notifications in iOS7.

I have developed an application for iOS6 and push notifications works very well. But, when I put that app in a iOS7 device, it doesn't run.

But something very strange happen. If I use Development key, my iOS7 device can receive push, but with Production key, It can't.

I can get my devide token for push but it is not able to receive anything.

Any idea?

This is my code:

Appdelegate.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // PUSH-CODE
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
    ....
}

// PUSH-CODE
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{    
    NSString *token = [[deviceToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:      [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
    token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
    NSLog(@"Token: %@", token);

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:token forKey:@"deviceToken"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Failed to get token, error: %@", error);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct device token? Note that when you sign your app with a sandbox provisioning profile you get a different device token than the one you get when using production provisioning profile. Also note that when you switched from iOS6 to iOS7 it's likely your device got a new device token (for each push env).

Comment: @Eran pls check the title: "Push notifications don't work in iOS7 but they work in iOS6" so his code is OK

Comment: I had the same issue, can anyone figure it out already?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just did a Google search for "ios7 push notification not working" since your question was only the 3rd I know already the response. It is not your fault, but Apple's one. The user need to connect they phone to iTunes to receive pushes. Sometimes hard factory reset, sometimes just turn off the device.

- iOSX.0 is a "come test it"
- iOSX.1 is a "we tried to fix some bugs, based on your flames"
- iOSX.2 stable, you are free to develop, anyhow in 3 month we have the next X.0 version :)

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by changing the app's push setting in push center. just close and then open

Comment: Need more explanation as your answer looks like a comment.

Comment: One my device can't get push token for our app downloading from appstore while the inHouse deployment working finely. I don't known why. Then I just go to the push center, turnoff our app's push, quit, and open again. Amazing thing occur, when I reopen our app, push token is there. I think the reason is some thing miss matching between